# evaluation of boolean expression in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

how to frame a query for the following expression in neo4j in a single query format ?
((A AND B) OR (C AND D) OR E) AND F AND G

consider 2 nodes X, Y where X-shows-> Y and a,b,c,d,e,f are different nodes that  Y. refer the link for reference. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1v9NFme8mOYThU59rc7dLOjjND7tXwWTG

I have converted the boolean expression into a postfix expression. i am stuck at how to convert the postix expression to a neo4j query

Comment: Why do you have to express the expression in postfix notation, when Cypher uses infix notation (and you started out with infix notation to begin with)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are actually using infix notation (not postfix), the Cypher logical expression will have the same structure.

For example:

```
MATCH p=(x)-[:shows]->(y)
WHERE ((y.a AND y.b) OR (y.c AND y.d) OR y.e) AND y.f AND y.g
RETURN p;
```